# Prove that if $\int f^2$ and $\int( f'')^2$ converge, so does $\int (f')^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> **Question:**
>
> Let $f: [a,\infty) \to \Bbb R \in C^2$ and the two following integrals converge:
>   $$\int _a^\infty (f''(x))^2\,dx ,~~~~~~~~~ \int _a^\infty (f(x))^2\,dx$$
>
> Prove that $\int _a^\infty (f'(x)^2)\,dx$ converges as well.

**What we tried:**
Taylor expansion, Lagrange mean value theorem, integration by parts, comparison test, limit comparison test, none really helped us get there...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint 1**: Integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^\infty f'(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_a^\infty f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}f(x)\\
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}f'(b)f(b)-f'(a)f(a)-\int_a^\infty f(x)f''(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
**Hint 2**: As Giraffe points out, if $\int_a^\infty f'(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges, then by $(1)$, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)f(x)=\infty$. Since
$$
f(b)^2=\int_a^bf'(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
we get that $\int_a^\infty f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges.

---

By the comments, this seems to be a bit more involved than befits a hint, so I will explain in more detail. Note that what follows is not needed due to Hint 2, but the ideas used are more generally applicable, so I will leave it.

> **Claim 1**: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$

**Proof**: Suppose not; then, for some $\epsilon\gt0$ and all $x_0$, there is an $x\ge x_0$ so that $|f'(x)|\ge\epsilon$.

Since $\|f''\|_{L^2}\lt\infty$, we can choose a $b$ so that
$$
\int_b^\infty f''(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\le\epsilon^4\tag{1}
$$
Then, for any $x,y\ge b$ so that $|x-y|\le1$, Cauchy-Schwarz says
$$
\begin{align}
|f'(x)-f'(y)|
&\le\int_x^y|f''(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\left(\int_x^y|f''(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}|x-y|^{1/2}\\[9pt]
&\le\epsilon^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
For any $x_0\ge b+1$, we can choose an $x\ge x_0$ so that $|f'(x)|\ge\epsilon$. If $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ have the same sign, let $I=[x,x+1]$, otherwise, let $I=[x-1,x]$.

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

By $(2)$, for $t\in I$, $|f'(t)|\ge\epsilon-\epsilon^2$ and $|f(t)|\ge\left(\epsilon-\epsilon^2\right)|t-x|$. Thus,
$$
\int_If(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\ge\frac13\left(\epsilon-\epsilon^2\right)^2\tag{3}
$$
By supposition, we can find infinitely many points so that $|f'(x)|\ge\epsilon$. Therefore,
$$
\int_b^\infty f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{diverges}\tag{4}
$$
giving us a contradiction. **QED**

> **Claim 2**: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

**Proof**: Suppose not; then, for some $\epsilon\gt0$ and all $x_0$, there is an $x\ge x_0$ so that $|f(x)|\ge\epsilon$.

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$, we can choose a $b$ so that for all $x\ge b$,
$$
|f'(x)|\le\epsilon^2\tag{5}
$$
Then, for any $x,y\ge b$ so that $|x-y|\le1$, the Mean-Value Theorem says
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|
&\le\max_{t\in[x,y]}|f'(t)||x-y|\\
&\le\epsilon^2\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
For any $x_0\ge b+1$, we can choose an $x\ge x_0$ so that $|f(x)|\ge\epsilon$. For any $t\in[x-1,x+1]$, $|f(t)|\ge\epsilon-\epsilon^2$. Thus,
$$
\int_{x-1}^{x+1}f(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\ge2\left(\epsilon-\epsilon^2\right)^2\tag{7}
$$
By supposition, we can find infinitely many points so that $|f(x)|\ge\epsilon$. Therefore,
$$
\int_b^\infty f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{diverges}\tag{8}
$$
giving us a contradiction. **QED**

Comment: So, how do we argue that $f'(b)f(b)$ converges?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I'd was going leaving that out, but I've added a second hint rather than putting it in a comment

Comment: Yes, but I do not see how it helps. How do we know the two integrals converge? I am thinking of a situation such as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/536472/462).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I modified my second hint right after I posted it.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I think I have taken care of things now :-)

Comment: Rob, how does the argument go? If $|x-y|\le 1$ and $x,y\ge b$ then $|f'(x)-f'(y)|=|f''(t)||x-y|\le |f''(t)|$ for some $t$ between $x$ and $y$. If $|f'(x)-f'(y)|>\epsilon^2$, then $|f''(t)|^2\ge \epsilon^4$. This is not yet enough to contradict $\int_b^\infty f''(x)^2\,dx<\epsilon^4$, though, and I fear I'm missing an obvious argument.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Since we can choose an interval as far up the real line on which $\int_If(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\ge\frac13\left(\epsilon-\epsilon^2\right)^2$ , we are contradicting that $\int_a^\infty f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ is finite

Comment: No, no. I am just asking how you conclude $|f'(x)-f'(y)|\le\epsilon^2$.

Comment: (As pointed out in a now deleted comment, the inequality that was troubling me follows from Cauchy-Schwarz: $|f'(x)-f'(y)|=|\int_x^y f''(t)\,dt|\le|x-y|^{1/2}\bigl(\int_x^y f''(t)^2\,dt\bigr)^{1/2}\le\epsilon^2$.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: sorry for the obscure answer. I have expanded the more complicated arguments.

Comment: @Giraffe: yes, $\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)^2=f'(x)f(x)$. I tried to use that in a second hint and didn't get it right. Thanks. I hope you don't mind that I incorporated that.

Answer (score 10):

By [Taylor's expansion with integral form of the remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder),
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+f'(x)+g(x),\tag{1}$$
where 
$$g(x)=\int_x^{x+1}(x+1-t)f''(t)~dt.\tag{2}$$
By $(1)$, [Minkowski's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) and $\int_a^\infty (f(x))^2dx<\infty$, to show 
$\int_a^\infty (f'(x))^2dx<\infty$, it suffices to show that
$$\int_a^\infty (g(x))^2dx<\infty.\tag{3}$$
By $(2)$ and [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2),
$$(g(x))^2\le \int_x^{x+1}(x+1-t)^2dt\cdot \int_x^{x+1}(f''(t))^2dt=\frac{1}{3}\int_x^{x+1}(f''(t))^2dt.\tag{4}$$
By $(4)$, [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and $\int_a^\infty (f''(x))^2dx<\infty$,
$$3\int_a^\infty (g(x))^2dx\le\int_a^\infty\left(\int_x^{x+1}(f''(t))^2dt\right)dx\le \int_a^\infty\left(\int_{t-1}^tdx\right)(f''(t))^2dt<\infty,$$
which completes the proof of $(3)$.

Answer (score 7):

This solution is quite unsatisfactory to me for its seemingly unnecessary complexity, but I post it anyway.

We introduce two lemmas

> **Lemma 1.** Assume $g(x) : [a, \infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ is absolutely integrable and continuous. Then
>   $$ \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)e^{-sx} \, dx = \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) \, dx. $$

and

> **Lemma 2.** Assume $g(x) : [a, \infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ is non-negative and continuous. Then regardless of the convergence of the integral,
>   $$ \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)e^{-sx} \, dx = \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) \, dx. $$

By integrating by parts,

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{R} \{ f'(x) \}^{2} e^{-sx} \, dx
&= \Big[ f(x)f'(x)e^{-sx} \Big]_{a}^{R} - \int_{a}^{R} f(x)f''(x) e^{-sx} \, dx \\
&\quad + \left[ \frac{s}{2} f(x)^{2} e^{-sx} \right]_{a}^{R} + \frac{s^{2}}{2} \int_{a}^{R}
f(x)^{2} e^{-sx} \, dx. \end{align*}

From CS-inequality,

$$ |f'(x)| \leq |f'(a)| + \left| \int_{a}^{x} f''(t) \, dt \right| \leq |f'(a)| + \sqrt{x - a} \left( \int_{a}^{\infty} f''(t)^{2} \, dt \right)^{1/2} $$

and hence both $f$ and $f'$ are of polynomial growth. So taking $R \to \infty$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{\infty} \{ f'(x) \}^{2} e^{-sx} \, dx
&= - f(a)f'(a)e^{-sa} - \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)f''(x) e^{-sx} \, dx \\
&\quad - \frac{s}{2} f(a)^{2} e^{-sa} + \frac{s^{2}}{2} \int_{a}^{\infty}
f(x)^{2} e^{-sx} \, dx. \end{align*}

Taking $s \to 0^{+}$, Lemma 1 and 2 show that

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{\infty} \{ f'(x) \}^{2} \, dx = - f(a)f'(a)- \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)f''(x) \, dx. \end{align*}

Since the right-hand side is finite, the same is true for the left-hand side and the proof is complete.

---

**Addendum. (Proof of Lemmas)**

> *Proof of Lemma 1.* For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $R$ such that $\int_{R}^{\infty} |g(x)| \, dx < \epsilon$. Since $g(x)e^{-sx}$ is also absolutely integrable, its integral is well-defined and
>   $$ \left| \int_{a}^{R} g(x)(1 - e^{-sx}) \, dx \right| \leq \int_{a}^{R} |g(x)| (1 - e^{-sx}) \, dx + \epsilon. $$
>   Taking $\limsup$ as $s \to 0^{+}$, followed by $\epsilon \to 0$, we obtain the desired result. ////

and

> *Proof of Lemma 2.* Let $I$ denote the integral on the right-hand side and $J$ denote the limit of the left-hand side. On the one hand, from the following inequality
>   $$ \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)e^{-sx} \, dx \leq \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) \, dx, $$
>   we have $J \leq I$. On the other hand, for each fixed $R > a$ we have
>   $$ \int_{a}^{R} g(x) \, dx = \lim_{s\to 0^{+}} \int_{a}^{R} g(x)e^{-sx} \, dx \leq J. $$
>   Thus taking $R \to \infty$ we obtain $I \leq J$ and the equality follows. ////